# Best way to create directory if not exists, but do not modify if exists

Tags: ansible

I would like to create a new directory with a specified mode/owner but *only* if it does not yet exist.

I can do it by first checking stat:

```
- name: Determine if exists
  stat:
    path: "{{ my_path }}"
  register: path

- name: Create path
  file:
    path: "{{ my_path }}"
    owner: someuser
    group: somegroup
    mode: 0775
    state: directory
  when: not path.stat.exists
```

Is it possible to do this without the extra step?

If not, is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you mean that you do not what to change the owner/group/mode in case the directory is already there? If not, your verification is useless as the dir will only be created/changed if it is not aligned to the description.

Comment: @Zeitounator correct: do not update owner/group if the dir already exists.

It's a long story on "why" but basically any pre-existing permissions/owner/group take precedence over what's defined in this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ansible can be used to *manage* the directory in question, always ensuring that it will have the defined ownership and permissions irrespective of whether it exists or not.

If you want to avoid any chances of modifying an existing directory for some reason, the way you accomplished it using Ansible modules (requiring two tasks) is correct.

However, if you do need to accomplish this in 1 step - you can use the [command module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/command_module.html) to run the `install` command to create directory.

Example:

```yaml
- name: Create path
  command:
    cmd: "install -o someuser -g somegroup -m 0775 -d {{ my_path }}"
    creates: "{{ my_path }}"
```

Here we are using the `creates` property to prevent the command from running when the path already exists.

Comment: Not the answer I wanted to hear, but if relying on `command` is the only way, then so be it. If the `file` module supported "creates" directive that would help me in this particular use-case, but it doesn't.

Comment: The `creates` property does make `command` module idempotent when the checks are as simple as whether a given path exists.